# WDK, winusb, installing usb drivers for all ports

Tags: winusb

Every time I insert my USB device in a new port, the OS keep asking me to provide a driver and this is quite annoying since this is the same device. I read some similar posts over internet but I don't understands quite sure how my device should present itself to Windows XP and get the driver automatically after it has installed once.

Perhaps this is about serial number in descriptor (which in my case is missing since I've read this needs to be absolutely unique and this falls in another problem)?

Comment: Windows XP or Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well known problem with Windows XP, which does not seem to have good solution (it is especially annoying if you use unsigned drivers).

However, Windows XP should only ask once per USB port - plugging in second time to the same USB port does not trigger driver reinstall sequence.

This issue is fixed in Windows 7 (provided you have signed drivers for your hardware).

Comment: yes, this is true. Once driver is installed for one port, things are normally. I can plug/unplug anytime without prompting for driver. I wonder if exist a solution (say to include in my install kit) to trick OS has drivers for all USB ports, at least for existing per machine.

Comment: for me its same for win 7 ultimate, i have plugged my usb mouse to another port and it started to search driver, but funny was when my friend plugged in "microsoft" mouse and it searched for driver for its own product.